# How to give the rest of letters default color

Tags: reactjs

```js
this.state = { 
      rows: rowsDefault,
      columns: columnsDefault,
      color: {
        B: { // RED
          r: '255',
          g: '99',
          b: '132',
          a: '0.4'
        },
        C: { // GREEN
          r: '75',
          g: '192',
          b: '192',
          a: '0.4'
        },
        D: { // BLUE
          r: '0',
          g: '96',
          b: '255',
          a: '0.4'
        },
        E: { // ORANGE
          r: '239',
          g: '108',
          b: '0',
          a: '0.4'
        },
        F: { // BROWN
          r: '62',
          g: '39',
          b: '34',
          a: '0.4'
        },
        G: { // DEFAULT
          r: '96',
          g: '125',
          b: '139',
          a: '0.4'
        }
      }

render() {
  let alphabet = ['B','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'];

  const data = {
      labels: [...this.state.rows.map(x => x.A)],
      datasets: alphabet.map(value => {
      return{
        label: this.state.rows[0][value],
        data: this.state.rows.map(x => x[value]),
        backgroundColor: `rgba(${this.state.color[value].r}, ${this.state.color[value].g}, ${this.state.color[value].b}, ${this.state.color[value].a})`
      }}),
    };
}
```

For the first few letters I'm using different colors and for the rest of the letters I want to use the default color at `G`. How do I give the rest of the letters the default color `G` contains, rest of the letters being letters that come after `G`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
    datasets: alphabet.map(value => {
        let color = this.state.color[value] || this.state.color.G
        return{
            label: this.state.rows[0][value],
            data: this.state.rows.map(x => x[value]),
            backgroundColor: `rgba(${color.r}, ${color.g}, ${color.b}, ${color.a})`
        }
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a method for getting color from state

```
constructor(props) {
  // ..
  this.getColor = this.getColor.bind(this)
}

getColor(value) {
  return this.state.color[value] || this.state.color.G
}

render(){
  // ..
  backgroundColor: `rgba(${this.getColor[value].r}, ${this.getColor[value].g}, ${this.getColor[value].b}, ${this.getColor[value].a})`
  // ..
}
```